# Expresso Store: checkout and order custom field w/ amout value - how to calculate total

Tags: expresso-store, custom-fields, checkout, custom-order-fields

I have added an order custom field to the checkout process named "Would you like this order gift wrapped?" and there is one choice (check box) which is passing value, which is marking that order as a gift, but now store owner has decided to have added some $ amount to the total when that options is checked.

My code looks like:

```
          <td>Would you like this order gift wrapped?</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="order_custom1" /> Yes</td>
            <td style="text-align:right"><input type="hidden" value="5.00" name="order_custom2" /> $5.00</td>
        </tr>
```

Now how I can update total with value of order_custom2 when order_custom1 is not empty on Update Total (or auto update total w/ jQuery on check box checked event)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a product instead of a custom order field.

In Store 2, the checkout tag and add to cart tag both submit to the same URL, so you can use this to add optional products to the cart during checkout.

To do this, the high level overview is that you simply submit a hidden field with the entry_id along with the standard update cart fields.

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][entry_id]" value="123" />
<!-- hidden input so that unselecting the checkbox submits 0 quantity -->
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][update_qty]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[0][update_qty]" value="1" selected /> Gift wrapping?
```

`update_qty` is exactly like `item_qty`, except that it overwrites any existing quantity in the cart rather than adding to it.

The only difference between this and the regular add to cart form is that you have to wrap the inputs with `items[num][]`. This allows multiple products to be added/updated at once.

This is similar to how the [product form tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_form_tag.html) works (they all submit to the same endpoint).

Comment: So I have create a product named "Gift Wrapping" with given amount value (price), then during the checkout process I can use example above to add it to the process. Am I right? Also do I need to count items[num] already in the cart to get proper value for that? Not sure about that part.

Comment: Correct. You shouldn't need to worry whether the item is already in the cart when using `update_qty`, because it will overwrite the existing quantity. Just make sure you don't display the product in the regular `{items}` list (you can exclude it using `{if entry_id != "123"}`.

Comment: The `num` you use in `items[num][]` shouldn't matter, as long as it doesn't clash with the `{key}` used by one of the other items in the checkout. I used `0` above which should work fine.

Comment: All looks fine, but how can I subtract value when "Gift Wrapping" was checked off after cart update?

Comment: Never mind - got it to work by adding `<input type="hidden" name="items[0][update_qty]" value="0"  />` before the checkbox.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear this worked for you.

Comment: I've added a note about the hidden input to my answer.